# Plural and singular in the parallel structure with OR

Tags: grammatical-number

John, Anne, or Peter (is/are) going to do it.

Giving your mother flowers or buying a card (is a great idea / are great ideas) for Mother's day gift.

I am aware of the rule saying that two singular subjects connected by or or nor require a singular verb. My American friends say that "is" does not sound natural in the first sentence and "are" sounds valid in the second one (as well as "is"). I am a bit confused

What grammar rule have you used? Is the alternative option grammatically correct or incorrect? If it was incorrect, why?

Comment: If only one person can actually do the thing that John, Anne and Peter have all volunteered for, I would use _is_. I don't see the options in the second sentence as mutually exclusive, so I would probably use _and/or_ with _are_!

Answer (score 1):

> John, Anne, or Peter (is/are) going to do it.

> Giving your mother flowers or buying a card (is a great idea / are great ideas) for Mother's day gift.

All the nouns in the examples above are singular, and we use the singular verb *is*.

In case we have a mix of singular and plural nouns, follow Rule (3) below.

> 2. When two or more singular nouns or pronouns are connected by or or nor, use a singular verb.

> The book or the pen is in the drawer.

> 3. When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb.

> The boy or his friends run every day.

> His friends or the boy runs every day.

[Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html)